# No signature of method: build_dvpx1fhh7s6mxy8ba6vkbiw13.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_dvpx1fhh7s6mxy8ba6vkbiw13$_run_closure 2)

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

[image]

this is the error I'm getting

[image]

this is my app level build.gradle